# Watch Coursera's videos with the video app on Jelly Bean

Tags: applications, browser, 4.1-jelly-bean, video

Coursera has a html5 based video viewer that works on the android browser on Jelly Bean, but I would like instead to use the video app, in order to have full screen and better controls.
On my Kindle Fire (first version) the Silk browser automatically opens the video with the video app and then returns to the html5 player when the video ends.
Is there a way to achieve this on Jelly Bean?

I am using a galaxy nexus S but shouldn't matter.
Thanks!

Comment: What browser are you using (Stock, Chrome, etc.)?

Comment: I am using stock

Comment: I tried now also with Chrome, and behaves exactly like Stock, it opens the html5 player which has tiny control buttons.

Comment: Have you tried downloading it? IIRC there are download buttons on the right.

Comment: I would not be surprised if this was due to added HTML5 support in Android 4.0 where as the original Kindle Fire is based on Android 2.3 and was lacking in HTML5 support.

Comment: @RichardBorcsik I know I can download it, but really I would like to just stream it.

Comment: @ZnewmaN I do not think so, in the Kindle Fire I see the interface, and in fact I can also answer the questions, so the HTML5 interface is definitely working, just as soon as the video starts, it switches from the browser to the video app.

Comment: Try installing an alternative video player like [Mx Video Player](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mxtech.videoplayer.ad). It should prompt you when you start the video to ask you if you want to open it with that or the browser. If the default video player doesn't show up there that would mean the intents are not properly set up in the app's manifest.

Comment: thanks @RichardBorcsik I tested Mx Video Player, both using Stock and Chrome, but it does not start when I start the video, I still see the Coursera HTML5 player.

Comment: it looks like nobody on stackexchange knows how to achieve this, so there is no answer.

Answer (score 1):

I just download the videos upfront and watch them with [MX Player](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mxtech.videoplayer.ad).

Comment: thanks, but I do not want to download the videos upfront. And if I download them, then I can just play them with the default video app.

Comment: @AndreaZ What video app do you want it to open with then?

Comment: any app would be fine, I'd prefer the stock video app but it does not matter. the point is that I do not want to download them upfront, but to stream them.

Comment: I tried a random course on there, after I pushed play, I pushed the "full screen" button that is in the bottom right of the video and it went full screen and the buttons were a lot easier to use.

Answer (score 1):

Is the `Coursera HTML5 player` an app installed onto the device? If so, have you tried disabling it in the app settings menu?

From ICS, system apps could be disabled.

Comment: No, it is just embedded in the Coursera web page

Answer (score -1):

There are a number of unofficial applications in the market (Google Play, Amazon). I've also developed my own application: [Coursera On The Go](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.realex). A free version is here! [Coursera On The Go Free](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.realex.free)